# Cambiar imagen dependiendo del sexo con una condicion

Tags: php

```html
    <?php
    include "conexion.php";

    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from usuarioss where correo = '$email'");
    $arr=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
    ?>
    
<div class=" file-drop-zone clearfix">
    <div class="file-preview-thumbnails clearfix"><div class="file-default-preview clickable" tabindex="-1"><img src="samples/default-profile-female.jpg" alt="Your Avatar" style="width: 180px; height: 160px;"><h6 class="text-muted"></h6></div></div>
    <div class="file-preview-status text-center text-success"></div>
    <div class="kv-fileinput-error"></div>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Tengo este codigo donde muestro por default una imagen como tipo de perfil, es un icono, estoy buscando como hacer una condicion de que por ejemplo la persona que se logueo es hombre se ponga otro icono para persona masculina, en mi base de datos tengo una columna llamada sexo que ahi es donde se guarda si es femenino o masculino, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Y qué dato usarías para determinar que el usuario se ha identificado con una opción dada? No es claro en tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` para comparar la columna.  Algo asi:

```
<?php
    include "conexion.php";

    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from usuarioss where correo = '$email'");
    $arr=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
?>

<div class=" file-drop-zone clearfix">
    <div class="file-preview-thumbnails clearfix">
      <div class="file-default-preview clickable" tabindex="-1">
      <?php
        if($arr['sexo'] == 'femenino') { 
      ?>
          <img src="samples/default-profile-female.jpg" alt="Your Avatar" style="width: 180px; height: 160px;">
      <?php
        } else {
      ?>
          <img src="samples/default-profile-male.jpg" alt="Your Avatar" style="width: 180px; height: 160px;">
      <?php
        }
      ?> 
        <h6 class="text-muted"></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="file-preview-status text-center text-success"></div>
    <div class="kv-fileinput-error"></div>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!